# VBA to loop through email attachments and save based on given criteria

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

This is a follow up from a previous question ([VBA to save attachments (based on defined criteria) from an email with multiple accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937850/vba-to-save-attachments-based-on-defined-criteria-from-an-email-with-multiple))

**Scenario:** I have a code that loops through all e-mails in a certain outlook account, and saves the attachments to a selected folder. Previously, my problem was selecting which folder (and account) from where to extract the attachments (this was solved with a suggestion from the previous question).

**Issue 1:** The code is presenting a "Type Mismatch" error at the line:

```
Set olMailItem = olFolder.Items(i)
```

**Issue 2:** As stated in the question title, my main objective is to loop through all the attachments and save only those that have a given criteria (excel file, with one sheet name "ASK" and one named "BID"). More than a simple If to account for these criteria, I have to either download all files to "temp folder", to the selection and put the final resulting files in the output folder, or download everything to the final folder and delete the files that do not meet the criteria.

**Problem:** I can't seem to find the way to do either of those operations.

**Question:** How would one do that? And which of those two would be more efficient?

**Code:**

```
Sub email()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim olNameSpace As Object
Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olFolder As Object
Dim olFolderName As String
Dim olAtt As Outlook.Attachments
Dim strName As String
Dim sPath As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer
Dim olSubject As String
Dim olSender As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Integer

'delete content except from row 1
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FileNames").Rows(2 & ":" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FileNames").Rows.count).Delete

'set foldername and subject
olFolderName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("D10")
'olSubject = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("D16")
olSender = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("D16")

sPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
sPathstr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)

Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'check if folder is subfolder or not and choose olFolder accordingly
'Set olFolder = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(olFolderName)
Set olFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("email@email.com").Folders("Inbox")

If (olFolder = "") Then
    Set olFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("email@email.com").Folders("Inbox")
End If

'loop through mails
h = 2
For i = 1 To olFolder.Items.count
    Set olMailItem = olFolder.Items(i)

    'check if the search name is in the email subject
    'If (InStr(1, olMailItem.Subject, olSubject, vbTextCompare) <> 0) Then
    If (InStr(1, olMailItem.Sender, olSender, vbTextCompare) <> 0) Then

        With olMailItem

                strName = .Attachments.Item(j).DisplayName

                'check if file already exists
                If Not Dir(sPathstr & "\" & strName) = "" Then
                .Attachments(j).SaveAsFile sPathstr & "\" & "(1)" & strName
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FileNames").Range("A" & h) = "(1)" & strName
                Else
                .Attachments(j).SaveAsFile sPathstr & "\" & strName
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FileNames").Range("A" & h) = strName
                End If

                h = h + 1
            Next

        End With

    End If
Next 

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Download complete!", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Done"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Issue 1 :

You probably have so meeting invites or something other than a regular mail in your folder.
Check the `Class` property of the `Item` to see if it's `olMail`

### Issue 2 :

I'll go with error handling, here :

1. Save in temp folder with the appropriate name
2. Open the file
3. Try to get to the sheets
4. If there is an error, just close the file
5. If there is no error, save the file in destination folder

Full code :

```
Sub email_DGMS89()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim olNameSpace As Object
Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olFolder As Object
Dim olFolderName As String
Dim olAtt As Outlook.Attachments
Dim strName As String
Dim sPath As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer
Dim olSubject As String
Dim olSender As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Integer

Dim TempFolder As String: TempFolder = VBA.Environ$("TEMP")
Dim wB As Excel.Workbook


'delete content except from row 1
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FileNames").Rows(2 & ":" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FileNames").Rows.Count).Delete

'set foldername and subject
olFolderName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("D10")
'olSubject = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("D16")
olSender = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("D16")

sPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
sPathstr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)

Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'check if folder is subfolder or not and choose olFolder accordingly
'Set olFolder = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(olFolderName)
Set olFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("email@email.com").Folders("Inbox")

If (olFolder = "") Then
    Set olFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("email@email.com").Folders("Inbox")
End If

'loop through mails
h = 2
For i = 1 To olFolder.items.Count
    '''Const olMail = 43 (&H2B)
    If olFolder.items(i).Class <> olMail Then
    Else
        Set olMailItem = olFolder.items(i)

        'check if the search name is in the email subject
        'If (InStr(1, olMailItem.Subject, olSubject, vbTextCompare) <> 0) Then
        If (InStr(1, olMailItem.Sender, olSender, vbTextCompare) <> 0) Then

            With olMailItem
                For j = 1 To .Attachments.Count
                    strName = .Attachments.Item(j).DisplayName

                    'check if file already exists
                    If Not Dir(sPathstr & "\" & strName) = vbNullString Then
                         strName = "(1)" & strName
                    Else
                    End If

                    '''Save in temp
                    .Attachments(j).SaveAsFile TempFolder & "\" & strName
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FileNames").Range("A" & h) = strName

                    '''Open file as read only
                    Set wB = workbooks.Open(TempFolder & "\" & strName, True)
                    DoEvents

                    '''Start error handling
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set sh = wB.sheets("ASK")
                    Set sh = wB.sheets("BID")
                    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                        '''Error = At least one sheet is not detected
                    Else
                        '''No error = both sheets found
                        .Attachments(j).SaveAsFile sPathstr & "\" & strName
                    End If
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sh = Nothing
                    wB.Close
                    On Error GoTo 0

                    h = h + 1
                Next j

            End With

        End If
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Download complete!", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: My head just exploded with the cleverness of your solution. Seriously, all I could achieve so far was a gigantic convoluted mess, and you found such an elegant solution. That's the kind of VBA skill and knowledge I wish I had!

Comment: @DGMS89 : Haha too much compliments!^^ Glad I could help and you'll see after 6/7 years of practice, googling/SOing and headaches, you'll pick up a few tricks! ;) The code could be improved but except if you have a huge amount to handle, I'll guess this will do the trick! ;) (if you want to learn more, take a look at the Code Review SE site! ;) )

Comment: Thanks again for the help, I will be sure to check the Code Review SE.

Comment: Just one thing, if I change the "h = h + 1", to "Next h", would that avoid a "For without next" error?

Comment: @DGMS89 : I missed that! I've added `For j = 1 To .Attachments.Count`, you need to loop on the attachments! ;) Give the edit a try! ;)

Comment: @R3uK Thanks! Question: why is that line comming up twice (the next with an if statement)? I don't get it... [code] Set olFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("email@email.com").Folders("Inbox") [/code]